# how to put value for laravel collective file input

Tags: php, laravel, file, input

hello there i have edit form and it has 3 inputs two are text and one is file input so its edit form so i must put the value of the input so when the person submit it will just save his changes

the problem is that every time you enter this edit form it requires you to upload a picture and i want the file input to have its value fetched from the database just like the two text inputs how could i do that ?

```
{!! Form::model($work,['method' => 'PATCH','enctype' =>         
'multipart/form-data' ,'files' => true ,'action'=>
['worksgallarey@update_work','id'=>$work->id,]]) !!}

<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('title') ? ' has-error' : 
''}}">
  {{Form::label('title', 'Title')}}
  {{Form::text('title', $work->title, ['class' => 'form-control 
required' , 'placeholder' => 'Enter a title'])}}
</div>

<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('picture') ? ' has-error' : 
''}}">
    {!! Form::label('picture') !!}
    {!! Form::file('picture')!!}
</div>

<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('bio') ? ' has-error' : ''}}">
  {{Form::label('bio', 'Bio')}}
  {{Form::text('bio', $work->bio, ['class' => 'form-control 
required', 'placeholder' => 'Write a bio '])}}
</div>
  {{Form::submit('submit',['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
```

this is my code and i tried

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('picture') ? ' has-error' : 
''}}">
    {!! Form::label('picture') !!}
    {!! Form::file('picture' , $work->picture )!!}
</div>
```

but didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is not technically possible. It's a security measure - the browsing user needs to manually select the file to upload.

Comment: yeah thats is what its happening and i thought it will be boring for the user to upload his photo over and over again thats why i am looking for soultion although thanks for the answer i didn't know this thing ❤️

Comment: Yeah, I absolutely get what you mean. :)